# G++ for 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, g++, win64

Where can I get a GCC/G++ compiler for my 64-bit Windows 7 machine?

Comment: @Ken, @OJ: But some questions actually should be answered with a search engine.  There's not going to be any value added in the answers here, at best they will be links.  And links break.

Comment: @Ben, @OJ: Then you can downvote the question. But you can't post links to the site whose name will be filtered out of my comment. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: @Ben: Links can be edited and updated if they do break though And the results of a google search can vary even more, depending on time, language and location as well as individual search history. If you want to suggest a compiler, list it by name, and link to its website.

Comment: @jalf: GCC has changed its name as well as its website several times.

Comment: @Ben: and if someone follows a link from here to a dead website, all they have to do is post a comment pointing this out, and the answer can be edited so it contains the correct information.

Comment: This post is the first result in google for G++ windows 7 so maybe it would be a good idea to answer it correctly!!!

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: Is there something incorrect about my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.google.com/#q=win64+gcc

No matter how often the download page moves around, that should find it for you.

At the time of this post, the top result (and correct download site) was `http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/`

Since that time, the project has moved to http://mingw-w64.org/ and you can find the Windows install packages at http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds, which is now one of the top Google hits also.